# How to connect a detached earbud back to Apple Earphones?

Tags: ear-phones

I have ~3 year old Apple Earphones that come with iPhones. One of the earbuds, the one with volume controls, broke off with ~1 inch wire attached to it.

Can I get this physical damaged earbud be repaired to a working state by connecting the wires and then using heat shrink wrap over it to protect the wires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but the wires are **very** fine. I rely on a twisted joint without soldering.

One method to improve this is to use the “pre”glued heatshrink.

Some more info can be found at:

- [How do you stop headphone wires from breaking?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-you-stop-headphone-wires-from-breaking/13764#13764)
- [Possible to cut Heat Shrink tubing lengthwise and reattach?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/possible-to-cut-heat-shrink-tubing-lengthwise-and-reattach)